# Number of columns appear 9 instead of 10

Tags: java, android, for-loop

When I run my code, it displays 9 column instead of 10. How can I fix this?

```
public void maketable() {

    int index = 0;

    isOn = new Boolean[9][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            isOn[i][j] = true;
        }
    }

    location = new ImageButton[9][10];

    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        //TableRow.LayoutParams p = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //row.setLayoutParams(p);
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            location[a][b] = new ImageButton(this);
            location[a][b].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box1);
            location[a][b].setOnClickListener(Onclick);
            location[a][b].setId(index++);

            row.addView(location[a][b]);
        }
        tableLayout.addView(row, a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing the values of a and b after `row.addView(location[a][b]);`

Answer (score 2):

`for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)` goes from 0 to 8 only.

If you need `a` to go from 0 to 9 (so to have 10 rows), use:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
```

Comment: No sir,, i want to repeat loop 10 times. b=0; b<10; b++ ,,, but in this code, it repeats 9 times instead of 10. why it does not repeat 10 time ?

Comment: @MubasharJaved my bad. Try to identify which column is missed (for example use the way Der Golem suggested)

Comment: Just to be sure: Is it only not visible or does the cycle end at `b=8` instead of `9`? This should show us where the problem occurs.

Comment: yes, b goes to 8 and loop finish. but why ?? this is my Question,, :(

Comment: Can't see any reason why that doesn't work. And I can't repeat it (not equipped to develop for Android).Maybe just try to change the number of columns, so we can see, if it happens again.